# jQuery Syntax error in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

Can anyone tell me why this would generate a syntax error in Safari and not in Firefox?

```
toggle = function(){
        $("#type_new").hide();
        $("a[class^='toggle']").unbind('click').click(function(){
            $.class = $(this).attr("class");
            if($(":input."+$.class+".text").is(':visible')==true) $(this).find("small").html("Add New Type"); else $(this).find("small").html("Choose From Exisiting Types");
            $(":input."+$.class+".select").toggle();
            $(":input."+$.class+".text").toggle().val("");
        });
    };
```

The error comes here:

> $.class = $(this).attr("class");

Any simplification is welcome as well.  This works just fine in firefox.  Also you might ask why it's so complicated but sometimes I'll have more than one of these on a page so I need the function to know which one to handle.

Thanks.

Comment: Might help if you narrowed it down to the line you're getting the error on.

Comment: Did you try it in a different way, maybe just `var class = $(this).attr("class");`?

Comment: Jonathan Lonowski has given the correct answer, but it's also worth pointing out that assigning temporary variables as properties of the jQuery object probably isn't a very good idea. It could easily lead to problems with plugins that you add at a later date, or enhancements in later versions of jQuery. Just use a local variable: `var class = $(this).attr("class");`

Comment: (Although `var class` won't work, of course, for the same reason = try `var className`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define properties/variables named after a reserved word -- such as `class`.

This is why you find `Element.className` instead of `Element.class` in DOM.

For a list of them, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: +1. Also, the reason it works in Firefox is that this restriction on property identifiers will be removed in the forthcoming ECMAScript version 5 specification, and recent versions of Firefox already implement some parts of that spec.

Comment: Excellent thanks Jonathan. Any suggestions on simplifying that code?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace $.class with something else beacause i think that for some browser the "class" word is reserved.